# Casting integers as another char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm testing the code below, but the output just says

```
ptr char = (null)
```

Any clue why this is happening?

```
int buf[1024];
buf[0] = 10;
buf[1] = 0;
buf[2] = 1992;
buf[3] = 42;
buf[4] = 5;
char *ptr;
ptr = (char*)buf+2;
printf("ptr char = %s\n",*ptr);
```

I just experimented on the above code so that I could know part by part what the code below would do.
here is the code I'm working on

```
int fillNSendHttpReq(int8u seq, char* domain, char* uri, char method, char* contentType, char* otherHeader, int contentLen, char* content, unsigned char timeout, char moreData, char isHttps)

{
int16u encodedLen = moreData?contentLen|0x8000:contentLen; 

//if moredata = true then encodelen = contentlenBITWISEOR0x8000
char *ptr = NULL;
int8u buf[1024];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

buf[0] = SNIC_HTTP_REQ;
buf[1] = seq;
*((int16u*)&buf[2]) = 0x5000; //swapped
buf[4] = method;
buf[5] = timeout;



 if (isHttps) {
buf[0] = SNIC_HTTPS_REQ;//SNIC_HTTPS_REQ = 0
*((int16u*)&buf[2]) = 0xbb01; // 443 swapped
 }

ptr = (char*)buf+6; //convert in8u to char * ???
ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%s", domain)+1; //ptr = ptr + strlen(domain)+1
ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%s", uri)+1;
ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%s", contentType)+1;
ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%s", otherHeader)+1;
*((int16u*)ptr) = swap16(encodedLen);
ptr += 2;

if (contentLen) 
    memcpy(ptr, content, contentLen);

serial_transmit(CMD_ID_SNIC, buf, ptr-(char*)buf+contentLen, ACK_NOT_REQUIRED);
return 0;
```

the part I don't understand is that  `ptr-(char*)buf+contentLen`was assigned to the variable defined as `int` and so that got me confused on where my content went which was a char.

Comment: You're mixing `char *` and `int *`.  Don't do that.  Your compiler should be complaining loudly.

Comment: I'm sorry I was just experimenting because I'm trying to know what the code does(i'll edit and attach the code I'm working on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is of *some size*. When you add `2` to a `char*`, the pointer advances by two bytes; to advance it by the size of an `int`, you’d do `(char*)(buf + 2)`. Two bytes past `buf` might be `buf[1]`, or it might be half of `buf[0]`, but apparently it points to zero, because that’s what you get by dereferencing `ptr` later – `NULL` is `0`. When passing a string to `printf`, you don’t dereference it first.

I don’t really know how to fix that part, though, because it just doesn’t make a lot of sense. If your code is close to your intent, then this is probably what it should be:

```
char *ptr = (char*)(buf + 2);
printf("ptr char = %s\n", ptr);
```

in which case it’ll print either zero or one characters with your example `buf`.

Comment: I've edited my question in order to let you see what function I'm trying to dissect and understand.

Comment: @user3136985: That’s quite a bit different. Importantly, `buf` is an array of `int8u`, which is (presumably) equivalent to `unsigned char` – *not* `int`. The subtraction there is just a way to get the length of the data added between `ptr = (char*)buf+6` and `serial_transmit` by the `sprintf`s and the `memcpy`.

Comment: that's what I thought, but then again it got me confused when I was thinking about the actual content that has to be passed as a POST request, and so I doubted and tried to clarify it. 

Thank you for the info good sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ptr;
ptr = (char*)buf+2;
printf("ptr char = %s\n",*ptr);
```

`ptr` is a char pointer, so `*ptr` is the character it points to. You passed a character as parameter while the `printf` is waiting for a "string" (char pointer) so it crashed

Previously you have assigned `ptr = (char*)buf+2;` so ptr is now pointing to *halfway between `buff[0]` and `buff[1]`*, and `*ptr == 0` (since `buf[0] = 10;`, the third byte in buff is zero regardless of endianness, assuming `sizeof(int) >= 4`), so it represents a NULL value when `printf` reads it as a pointer. That's why you see the output

Use this

```
printf("ptr char = %s\n", ptr);
```

But then you'll see another empty output since ptr[0] is now `'\0'`

Comment: oh I see, sorry I'm just kinda starting to grasp the idea that's why I asked so I could be corrected. Thank you!